# writetable without dimension names

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I'm trying to write a CSV from a table using `writetable` with `writetable(..., 'WriteRowNames', true)`, but when I do so, Matlab defaults to putting `Row` in the (1,1) cell of the CSV. I know I can change `Row` to another string by setting `myTable.Properties.DimensionNames{1}` but I can't set that to be blank and so it seems like I'm forced to have some text in that (1,1) cell.

Is there a way to leave the (1,1) element of my CSV blank and still write the row names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way to set any of the character arrays in the [`'DimensionNames'` field](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table-properties.html#property_d0e987104) to either empty or whitespace. One option is to create your .csv file as you do above, then use [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) to clear that first cell:

```
xlswrite('your_file.csv', {''}, 1, 'A1');
```

Even though the `xlswrite` documentation states that the file argument should be a .xls, it still works properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could use [`memmapfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) to modify the leading bytes of the file in memory.

For example:

```
% Set up data
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
T = table(Age, Height, Weight, BloodPressure, 'RowNames', LastName);

% Write data to CSV
fname = 'asdf.csv';
writetable(T, fname, 'WriteRowNames', true)

% Overwrite row dimension name in the first row
% Use memmapfile to map only the dimension name to memory
tmp = memmapfile(fname, 'Writable', true, 'Repeat', numel(T.Properties.DimensionNames{1}));
tmp.Data(:) = 32;  % Change to the ASCII code for a space
clear('tmp');  % Clean up
```

Which brings us from:

```
Row,Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure_1,BloodPressure_2
Smith,38,71,176,124,93
Johnson,43,69,163,109,77
Williams,38,64,131,125,83
Jones,40,67,133,117,75
Brown,49,64,119,122,80
```

To:

```
   ,Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure_1,BloodPressure_2
Smith,38,71,176,124,93
Johnson,43,69,163,109,77
Williams,38,64,131,125,83
Jones,40,67,133,117,75
Brown,49,64,119,122,80
```

Unfortunately not quite deleted, but it's a fun approach.

---

Alternatively, you can use MATLAB's [low level file IO](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-file-i-o.html) to copy everything after the row dimension name to a new file, then overwrite the original:

```
fID = fopen(fname, 'r');
fID2 = fopen('tmp.csv', 'w');
fseek(fID, numel(T.Properties.DimensionNames{1}), 'bof');
fwrite(fID2, fread(fID));
fclose(fID);
fclose(fID2);
movefile('tmp.csv', fname);
```

Which produces:

```
,Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure_1,BloodPressure_2
Smith,38,71,176,124,93
Johnson,43,69,163,109,77
Williams,38,64,131,125,83
Jones,40,67,133,117,75
Brown,49,64,119,122,80
```

Answer (score -1):

No, that is currently not supported. The only workaround I see is to use a placeholder as dimension name and to programmatically remove it from the file afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

```
writetable(T,fileFullPath,'WriteVariableNames',false);
```

When specify 'WriteVariableNames' as false (default one is true), then the variable/dimension names will NOT be written in the output file.

Ref link: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html

Comment: This ignores the main premise of the question.